# Getting problems while testing c_icap

Tags: cygwin

The drive link of the is https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gJLD-VEqo67wnEogyYvO-HrE8nwDRalC?usp=sharing
When I am testing c_icap in cywin it showing error when i run the server on the debug mode.
./configure
make LDFLAGS=-no-undefined
make install LDFLAGS=-no-undefined
c-icap -N -D -d 10
Its think its running the server
When i run the c_icap-client Its not showing any responses from the server
Help me to solve this please.

Comment: What error? Please provide details.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Missing information in your question : What is `c_icap`, how you configured and compiled it ? Or are you hoping we can look inside your system ? Do not use images but copy and paste the proper log.

Comment: I have edited the problem Please dont mind i am new to this kind of stuff i am an intern.